# Build FreeBSD Docker image using Ubuntu host OS

Tags: ubuntu, docker, freebsd

I know that in generally it is impossible to build FreeBSD Docker image on Linux host OS due to different kernels and sys calls.

However, I would like to know maybe there is a simple workaround to overcome this limitation?

P.S. I don't want to consider Vagrant usage inside Docker container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to run a BSD container on Ubuntu, just use a FreeBSD VM.

It was *possible* in 2015 to run [BSD containers](https://hub.docker.com/r/amontalban/freebsd/) on FreeBSD 11.1+ via an [experimental port of Docker](https://github.com/kvasdopil/docker) that uses ZFS, Jails and FreeBSD's 64bit Linux compatibility layer.

Comment: Unfortunately, using FreeBSD as a host OS is not a solution for me.

Comment: @user54 just in case https://fabrik.red you could create an image and use it as a host in many cloud providers